# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.products is not iterable. (but it is iterable)

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, json-server

I want to get unique value from a **JSON** array.

Data is coming from fetch API. Which is clearly iterable

[note the product variable is a sample of JSON, Actually, I am filling data from calling GetAllProducts() ]

```
products = 
[
  {
    "name": "APPLE 27 inch THUNDERBOLT DISPLAY",
    "show_room": "A iCenter",
    "stock": "1",
    "type": "DISPLAYS",
    "category": "APPLE",
    "id": "101"
  },
  {
    "name": "APPLE WIRELESS KEYBOARD",
    "show_room": "B iCenter",
    "stock": "2",
    "type": "MOUSE",
    "category": "MAC ACCESSORIES",
    "id": "107"
  }
]
```

Error occurs when I try to execute this funtion: getDistinctCategoryValues()

This is my **.ts** file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-list',
  templateUrl: './product-list.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-list.page.scss'],
})
export class ProductListPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dataService: DataService,
              private router: Router) {
    this.GetAllProducts();
    this.getDistinctCategoryValues();
  }

  products: any;


  ngOnInit() {
  }

  async GetAllProducts() {
    const response = await this.dataService.GetProducts();
    const dataService = await response.json();
    this.products = dataService;
    console.log(this.products);
  }

  getDistinctCategoryValues() {

    const lookup = {};
    const result = [];

    console.log(this.products);
    for (const item of this.products) {
      const currentVar = item.category;

      if (!(currentVar in lookup)) {
        lookup[currentVar] = 1;
        result.push(currentVar);
      }
    }

    console.log(result);
    return result;

  }
```

}

Now when I am running getDistinctCategoryValues() , I am getting error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.products is not iterable.
```

A strange thing is that,

1. When I `console.log()` from `GetAllProducts()`, all data is fine in the products variable
2. But When I `console.log()` from `getDistinctCategoryValues()`, product variable shows undefined

IDK what went wrong. Why data is vanished just 1 line later? [see the constructor]. My API is running and no error there.

[ Btw I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server for JSON ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your `GetAllProducts`is an async function , and it awaits response   `const response = await this.dataService.GetProducts()`; which means any code scoped inside the `GetAllProducts` function won't run, meanwhile anything running after the async function will run normal hence why your this.product will always return undefined
to solve this move the `getDistinctCategoryValues()` inside the await function or make `GetAllProducts` return products and then use it inside  `getDistinctCategoryValues()`, or use generator functions

Comment: so what should I do to save the data so that I can use later?

Comment: I have suggested some solutions have look at them

Comment: thanks for you answer, now if i execute getDistinctCategoryValues() inside GetAllProducts() , all is good. But I need to save it to a variable permanently.

Comment: just declare a variable and assign the new values to it

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change products: any; to products = [];
Every other think should work without any change.

and

> constructor(private dataService: DataService,
> private router: Router) {
> this.GetAllProducts();
> this.getDistinctCategoryValues();   }

Will not work. You need to move this.getDistinctCategoryValues(); to ngOnInit, or call this.GetAllProducts()